# LeftJoinAndMapOne with subquery in typeorm

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am new to typeorm and don't know how to handle this.

I need leftJoinAndMapOne with subquery without relationship (Just want to know is this possible or not).

Other question is can I use leftJoinAndMapOne inside leftJoinAndMapOne (nested)?

Can you help me for this?

```
await this.connection
            .getRepository(UserInfoEntity)
            .createQueryBuilder('user_info')
            .leftJoinAndMapOne(
                'user_info.roles',
                (qb) => {
                    return qb.select().from(UserHasOrganizationRoleEntity, 'orgRole');
                },
                'orgRole',
                'orgRole.userId = :userId AND orgRole.organizationId = :organizationId',
                {
                    userId: auth_user.userId,
                    organizationId: auth_user.organizationId,
                },
            )
            .where('user_info.id = :id', { id })
            .getRawMany();
```

Error:

> QueryFailedError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "orgrole"
>
> at new QueryFailedError (/Volumes/Project/Toptipi-node/node_modules/typeorm/error/QueryFailedError.js:11:28)
> at PostgresQueryRunner. (/Volumes/Project/Toptipi-node/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.js:247:31)
> at step (/Volumes/Project/Toptipi-node/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:141:27)
> at Object.throw (/Volumes/Project/Toptipi-node/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:122:57)
> at rejected (/Volumes/Project/Toptipi-node/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:113:69)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
> length: 120,
> severity: 'ERROR',
> code: '42P01',
> detail: undefined,
> hint: undefined,
> position: '1192',
> internalPosition: undefined,
> internalQuery: undefined,
> where: undefined,
> schema: undefined,
> table: undefined,
> column: undefined,
> dataType: undefined,
> constraint: undefined,
> file: 'parse_relation.c',
> line: '3459',
> routine: 'errorMissingRTE',
> query: 'SELECT "user_info"."id" AS "user_info_id", "user_info"."firstName" AS "user_info_firstName", "user_info"."title" AS "user_info_title", "user_info"."lastName" AS "user_info_lastName", "user_info"."gender" AS "user_info_gender", "user_info"."phoneNumber" AS "user_info_phoneNumber", "user_info"."organizationId" AS "user_info_organizationId", "user_info"."systemRoleId" AS "user_info_systemRoleId", "user_info"."userId" AS "user_info_userId", "user_info"."address" AS "user_info_address", "user_info"."cityId" AS "user_info_cityId", "user_info"."stateId" AS "user_info_stateId", "user_info"."countryId" AS "user_info_countryId", "user_info"."pincode" AS "user_info_pincode", "user_info"."joiningDate" AS "user_info_joiningDate", "user_info"."image" AS "user_info_image", "user_info"."imagePath" AS "user_info_imagePath", "user_info"."experience" AS "user_info_experience", "user_info"."expFile" AS "user_info_expFile", "user_info"."expFilePath" AS "user_info_expFilePath", "user_info"."createdAt" AS "user_info_createdAt", "user_info"."updatedAt" AS "user_info_updatedAt", "orgRole".* FROM "user_info" "user_info" LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM "user_has_organization_roles" "orgRole") "orgRole" ON orgRole.userId = $1 AND orgRole.organizationId = $2 WHERE "user_info"."id" = $3',
> parameters: [ '2', '1', '14' ]
> }